# How can a gas produce gravity?

Tags: gravity, gas

I’m asking this because, I heard that the gas does produce gravity. So, how does actually works? What’s the phenomenon for gas producing gravity?

Because, all what I want is a clear explanation in this.

Comment: any matter "produces" gravity, gas, liquid, solid, plasma...

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Ok, but how it is done? What’s he phenomenon? How can water, liquid, solid etc... produce gravity? I don’t see how the logic here.

Comment: What does "how" mean in this context?

Comment: @BenCrowell I mean, how the gas produce.

Comment: The amount of energy in a region determines the spacetime curvature of that region. Matter, whether gas, liquid or solid, is a rather condensed form of energy.

Comment: @AlexA Perhaps you could define for us what you mean by "produce gravity"

Comment: @AlexA, a gravitational field is an inherent property of mass.  The more mass you have, the more gravitational field it produces.  Any theoretical discussion regarding where mass comes from may have to wait ... the Higg's boson, the particle that imparts "mass" to matter, was only recently discovered and verified.  And note - any gas definitely has mass.

Answer (score 3):

It is a basic law of nature that matter (and energy too) does produce gravity. In Newton's theory it is just so, for no other reason than being a property of matter. In general relativity it is the same thing, but gravity is explained as a deformation of spacetime due to the presence of matter, so matter bends space time, just because it does, it a property of matter and energy.